# how to access the flutter bloc state variable to another screen bloc class and add event changes inside that class how to do that?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, mobile-development

here is the bloc class code , and here i added an event called NavItemVisibilityEvent
but when i call this event in another class the ui is not updating what's the issue inside this code.

```
class MainScreenBloc extends Bloc<MainScreenEvent, MainScreenState> {

  MainScreenBloc() : super( MainScreenInitial(itemVisibility: itemVisibility)) {

    on<NavigationLoadedEvent>((event,emit)async{
      print('inside loaded Event');
      List<bool>? loadedBoolList = await PrefManager.loadBoolList('navBarList');
       if(loadedBoolList == null)
         {
           print('inside loadedBoolList');
           emit(MainScreenInitial(itemVisibility: itemVisibility));
           emit(MainScreenLoadedState(currentIndex: 0,itemVisibility:itemVisibility,visible: true));
           // emit(MainScreenInitial(itemVisibility: itemVisibility));
         }else{
         print('after pref loaded Event');
         print('loadedBoolList $loadedBoolList');
         emit(MainScreenInitial(itemVisibility: loadedBoolList));
         emit(MainScreenLoadedState(currentIndex: 0,itemVisibility:loadedBoolList,visible: true));
       }

    });
    on<NavigationEvent>((event, emit) async{
         final currentState = state as MainScreenLoadedState;
      // List<bool> loadedBoolList = await PrefManager.loadBoolList('navBarList');
      //  print('loadedBoolList $loadedBoolList');
      emit(MainScreenLoadedState(currentIndex: event.currentIndex,
          itemVisibility: currentState.itemVisibility,visible: true
      ));
       // print('navList $navList');
       // if(navList == null)
       //   {
       //     navList = await PrefManager.loadBoolList('navBarList')??itemVisibility;
       //
       //   }else{
       //   navList = await PrefManager.loadBoolList('navBarList')??itemVisibility;
       //   emit(MainScreenState(currentIndex: event.currentIndex,
       //       itemVisibility:navList
       //   ));
       // }

    });
    on<NavigationHideEvent>((event,emit) {
      final currentState = state as MainScreenLoadedState;
      emit(MainScreenLoadedState(currentIndex: currentState.currentIndex,visible: event.visible,
          itemVisibility:currentState.itemVisibility));
    });

    on<NavItemVisibilityEvent>((event,emit) async {
      final currentState = state as MainScreenLoadedState;
      print('inside event visibility');
      emit(MainScreenLoadedState(currentIndex: currentState.currentIndex, itemVisibility:event.itemVisibility,
          visible: true));
       print('final event visibility ${event.itemVisibility}');
      await PrefManager.saveBoolList(event.itemVisibility!,'navBarList');
    });

  }
}
```

here's the state class code

```
class MainScreenState {
   MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenInitial extends MainScreenState {
  List<bool>? itemVisibility;
  MainScreenInitial({this.itemVisibility});
}
class MainScreenLoadedState extends MainScreenState{
  final int? currentIndex;
  final bool? visible;
  List<bool>? itemVisibility;
  MainScreenLoadedState({this.currentIndex, this.visible,this.itemVisibility});

}
```

here is the another bloc class i want to access the state variable of mainbloc class and when i call the NavItemVisibilityEvent inside this call its not updating the current ui.

```
for (var i in state.toggleFavStates) {
                          switch (i.key) {
                            case 'Chat':
                              print('iteration');
                              final state = mainScreenBloc.state;
                              print('state $state');
                              if(state is  MainScreenInitial)
                                {
                                  print('state value ${state.itemVisibility}');
                                  print('itemVisibility');
                                  navList = state.itemVisibility;
                                  print('navList $navList');
                                }
                              print('naVlistss: $navList');
                              navList?[1] = i.value;
                              context.read<MainScreenBloc>().add
                                (NavItemVisibilityEvent(
                                  key: i.key,
                                  singleItem: i.value,
                                  itemVisibility:navList));
                              //do this to that index.
                              break;
                            case 'Schedule':
                              // navList =  mainScreenBloc.state.itemVisibility;
                              navList?[2] = i.value;
                              context.read<MainScreenBloc>().add
                                (NavItemVisibilityEvent(
                                  key: i.key,
                                  singleItem: i.value,
                                  itemVisibility:navList));
                              break;
                            case 'Profile':
                              // navList =  mainScreenBloc.state.itemVisibility;
                              navList?[3] = i.value;
                              context.read<MainScreenBloc>().add
                                (NavItemVisibilityEvent(
                                  key: i.key,
                                  singleItem: i.value,
                                  itemVisibility:navList));
                              break;
  
                           default:
                        
                              break;
                          }
                        }
```

here in this above screen i am calling

````
                    ```
                       context.read<MainScreenBloc>().add
                             (NavItemVisibilityEvent(
                              key: i.key,
                              singleItem: i.value,
                              itemVisibility:navList));

                                                   ```
````

but its not updating the my ui state.
and also here iam using the code to access the mainScreenLoaded state variable value & is this the right way to access the state variable value from another Bloc screen class.

````
                    ``` 
                          final state = mainScreenBloc.state;
                          print('state $state');
                          if(state is  MainScreenInitial)
                            {
                              print('state value ${state.itemVisibility}');
                              print('itemVisibility');
                              navList = state.itemVisibility;
                              print('navList $navList');
                            }

                            
                         ```
````

Comment: Can you update the question with a minimal reproducible code of the other bloc. It's not clear where `mainScreenBloc` & `context` is coming from.

Comment: @Cabdirashiid mainScreenBloc is a separate class that contain bloc ,events & states class

Comment: If there's bloc A & B, variables & events of A must be accessed & emitted within B?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the entire context from question but as general rule of thumb, for bloc please make sure check these things ->

1. You have overridden hashcode and equal to operator in the state's and the custom models inside the state. I generally use https://pub.dev/packages/equatable package for ease of code for this.
2. Whenever you are trying to update a list item in state, firstly create a new list and then modify it and emit that. Also create copyWith methods and use that if you want to emit same state with different properties.

```
List newList = List.from(state.myList)
newList[index] = xyz
emit(state.copyWith(newList)
```

3. If you want the UI to be updated as soon as a new state is emited, make sure you use the BlocBuilder widet and have written the code inside that.
4. Make sure that scope of bloc is either global, i.e written in your main app or else is at least provided to new screen when you push the new screen. You can do that using

````
 Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
          value: BlocProvider.of<BlocX>(context),
          child: Screen2(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    ```
````

Comment: i just want to know that how to access a state variable value  of a bloc on another screens on the onPressed function and also i want to call event of another bloc and update that state.

Comment: for example i have a Bloc in MainScreen and a bloc in SettingsScreen(those are 2 different screens), here i want to access the state variable value of MainScreen inside the SettingsScreens method(or just inside of an onPressed function) and also i need to call MainScreenEvent inside this method for emmiting the changes.

Comment: Provide the bloc to the other screen. You can do this by using the BlocProvider.value widget. On the other screen, use the BlocBuilder widget to listen to the bloc's state. The BlocBuilder widget will rebuild the widget whenever the bloc's state changes.

Comment: @but this case i have already a BlocProvider.value of current bloc context that is settingsBloc , here i want the value of MainScreenBloc State

Comment: Here i am using Multiprovider Widget at the root of main.dart file

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve When you provide the bloc value using BlocProvider.value to the SettingsScreen, only then using context you will be able to access the bloc of MainScreen. Like context.read<MainScreenBloc>().add(EventName()).